# Sorting list of lists by numerical suffix at end of string in first element

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists like this:

```
table_data = [['vlan1', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.2.2'], 
              ['vlan100', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.110.2'], 
              ['vlan50', '0013.F200.0058', '192.168.30.2'], 
              ['vlan20', '0010.600a.7026', '192.168.30.4'], 
              ['vlan2', '70ca.9b99.6a82', '192.168.30.1']]
```

I want to sort it by vlan number, how can I do this? So vlan1 list, then vlan2 list etc

I've tried separating the numbers but I'm not sure what to do then, I think this not be the right way to do it.

```
for i in table_data:
        if i[0].startswith('vlan'):  
            vlan_number = i[0][4:]
```

I can do it with a single list like so:

```
sorted(table_data, key = lambda x: int(x.split("n")[1]))
```

but how to extend that to a list of lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sorted(table_data, key=lambda x: int(x[0][4:]))
```

In your orginal sorted-based solution, you should modify the lambda function. x[0] means the first column of each row. And x[0][4:] would skep the first 4 chars, which is "vlan".

Comment: +1 very nice! So easy to over complicate this, which I did :-)